rel preload in link tag is not working for shadow components
I have loaded the preload link tag in the head.
And then rendered a shadow component(welcome-comp) with the same href link tag inside it. The issue is still the link tag resource is downloading again. click on button to render component again , still the resource is downloading again. It is working fine for non shadow components.
HTML :
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="preload" type="text/css" as="style" href="style.css" />
    <script>
      class WelcomeComp extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
          this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
          let link = document.createElement('link');
          link.href = 'style.css';
          link.rel = 'stylesheet';
          this.shadowRoot.appendChild(link);
      
          let content = document.createElement('div');
          content.setAttribute('class', 'cls');
          content.setAttribute('id', 'cls');
          content.innerHTML = 'welcome here! check network tab new request triggered';
          this.shadowRoot.appendChild(content);
        }
      }
      customElements.define('welcome-comp', WelcomeComp);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="outlet">
      <welcome-comp></welcome-comp>
    </div>
    <button
      onclick='document.getElementById("outlet").appendChild(document.createElement("welcome-comp"))'>
      render new component
    </button>
  </body>
</html>

css :
.cls{color:red}

This issue occurs only in chromium based browsers, working fine in mozilla, safari browsers.

Report it as a bug: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/wizard

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/376304023
Reported @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks.
